# Adding where clause to aggregate query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

This is the query kibana has generated and it works as expected. But I want to add one more where clause to the query. The eventname should not start with "Describe" or "List".

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": 1490867646696,
              "lte": 1493459646696,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "eventName.keyword",
        "size": 5000,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Update:
I am not sure if this will correctly exclude the records.

```
      "must_not": [     
{ 
    "prefix" : { "eventName.keyword" : "Describe" }
},
{ 
    "prefix" : { "eventName.keyword" : "List" }
}
]
```

How to get this query back into kibana?

Comment: I have made some changes to the query. But how do I apply the new query to kibana?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/kibana-queries-filters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the expected results either of following ways:

**Method-1: Customizing existing query_string query**

Replace default `query_string` query `*` from Kibana search bar with following query string:

```
!(eventName.keyword: Describe* OR eventName.keyword: List*)
```

**Method-2: Adding filters in Kibana**

1. Add filter in Kibana as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-filter.html#field-filter)
2. Then [edit the filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-filter.html#filter-edit) and replace whole filter with following code:

`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "eventName.keyword": "Describe"
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "eventName.keyword": "List"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`

Comment: I am using Method 1. There are a lot of OR clause (not just 2). Is there any way to make it shorter?

Comment: If you make `eventName.keyword` as `default_field` then you can ignore field name prefix in query_string so eventually your  above query_string can be rewritten as `!(Describe* List*)` .